# PLSQL when trying to change value of length while loop gives error

Tags: oracle, plsql, while-loop

In my pl sql while loop i try to change the length of a number, which also then changes the length of my value on which my while loop is based the while loop stops working. The code is as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION neemrest(restnumber number)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
partrest NUMBER;
afternumber NUMBER;
BEGIN
WHILE LENGTH(TO_CHAR(restnumber))>9 LOOP
partrest := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(restnumber,1,10));
afternumber := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(restnumber,11,20));
restnumber := partrest||afternumber;
END LOOP;
RETURN MOD(restnumber,64);
END;
```

Now by taking each step seperatly i found that the problem liest in the last line of the while loop

```
restnumber := partrest||afternumber;
```

Now my question how can i change the lenght of my number whilst not breaking the while loop since this is vital for my function. and the usage of my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that you are trying to assign a value to a readonly parameter.

You should modify your function to be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION neemrest(restnumber in out number)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
partrest NUMBER;
afternumber NUMBER;
BEGIN
    WHILE LENGTH(TO_CHAR(restnumber))>9 LOOP
        partrest := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(restnumber,1,10));
        afternumber := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(restnumber,11,20));
        restnumber := partrest||afternumber;
    END LOOP;
RETURN MOD(restnumber,64);
END;
```

Comment: Yes, unless specified, a parameter is by default IN only.

Comment: Your answer is correct---+1, you should've pointed at my answer as it was wrong! I've deleted it BTW...

Comment: I forget to add in my code that i need to get the remainder of partrest, instead of just the number. However this agains breaks my code

Comment: Modified it to just use an IN OUT parameter. This function will return the remainder, then you will need to check the value of the parameter you passed in to get the resulting value.